# Regex for mobile number, phone number validation with some conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to validate both mobile number and phone number in regex. So the regex should pass all the below rules

1. There has to be at least 5 numerical.
2. The special characters like +,(),-, # are to be used only once
3. open and close brackets should exist mutually i.e., if an open bracket is used, It has to be closed mandatorily
4. Maximum numbers should be 20.

So to make this I have added this piece of code.

```
//validate phone
function validatePhone( phone ) {
    var regex = /^(?:(?:\(?(?:00|\+)([1-4]\d\d|[1-9]\d?)\)?)?[\-\.\ \\\/]?)?((?:\(?\d{1,}\)?[\-\.\ \\\/]?){0,})(?:[\-\.\ \\\/]?(?:#|ext\.?|extension|x)[\-\.\ \\\/]?(\d+))?$/i;
    return regex.test( phone );
}
```

But its not validating above all the conditions.

**Update**
It should accept all these phone numbers

```
(+355)250235
+91 123456789012
(+355) 250-236-236-789
(+355) 2502-3656-1236-8789
+920123456789012345987
(+355) 250235 #10
```

Comment: Just FYI, Google have a ***very*** comprehensive multi-national phone number validation library you can use for this: https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/tree/master/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for the url but can't we do that by using Regex?

Comment: Can you please update the question with some examples?

Comment: @Jobelle I have updated my question. Please check.

Comment: @NewUser Perhaps like this `^(?=(?:[^\n\d]*\d){5})(?!(?:[^\n\d]*\d){21})(?:\(\+\d+\)|\+\d+) ?\d+(?:-\d+)*$` https://regex101.com/r/EfsEqq/1 Note that this example `+920123456789012345987` has 21 numbers.

Comment: @Thefourthbird what needs to be done if I want to add `#` in the phone number as well? Just like this
`(+355) 250235 #10`

Comment: @NewUser Like this? https://regex101.com/r/9V7BYk/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird as of now it seems to be fine but we don't need to make + as mandatory one. One can use the phone number without adding +.

Comment: @NewUser You can make it optional https://regex101.com/r/RuMhjT/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assert at least 5 digits and not 21 digits.

Then match either the part with or without parenthesis and optionally match the part with # at the end.

```
^(?=(?:[^\n\d]*\d){5})(?!(?:[^\n\d]*\d){21})(?:\(\+?\d+\)|\+?\d+) ?\d+(?:-\d+)*(?: ?#\d+)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RuMhjT/1)

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the space and - (hyphen) using the below

```
 var temp =str.replace(/([\s\-])/g, '');
```

Then test it using the below reg ex

```
^((\(){1}(\+?\d{3}(\)){1})|(\+)?\d{3})(\d){2,17}$
```

Try use the below function

```
function validate (str){

 var temp =str.replace(/([\s\-])/g, '');  
  var patt = /^((\(){1}(\+?\d{3}(\)){1})|(\+)?\d{3})(\d){2,17}$/g;
  var result = patt.test(temp);
}
```

[Check This](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GNWQ9YCFLCRL)

[image]

Comment: Can't we remove + from the beginning. It should not be mandatory for using + at the beginning of numbers.

Comment: @NewUser Ans updated. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GODLQO42ZG7G